# Does the standard require EOF to be negative?

Tags: c, standards, c-standard-library

Is it written in the standard that `EOF` must be negative? 
On the contrary, `WEOF` is not required to be negative. Why?
The situation for `wchar_t` must not be in any way different from ordinary `char` (except where automatic promotion from `char` to `int` plays the role), because defining `wchar_t` as `char` is perfectly fine with the standard. Therefore, similar rules must apply.

Some quotations from glibc reference:

> if `wchar_t` is defined as `char` the type `wint_t` must be defined as `int` due to the parameter promotion.

> it would be legitimate to define `wchar_t` as `char`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is guaranteed to be negative. See C11

> **7.21 Input/output**
>
> **7.21.1 Introduction**
>
> 1 The header  defines several macros, and declares three types and many
>   functions for performing input and output.
>
> 3 ...
>
> **EOF**
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value

Comment: What is the **rationale** for this? Why WEOF is not required to be negative?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: There isn't a rationale; it is historically what was expected and the standard has said so, in 1989 and ever since.  It makes the sign of `EOF` different from the valid character values returned by `getchar()` and friends, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just stop saying about history. Do you thing those folks were stupid? I'm trying to understand the real cause.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: History is actually the main reason, my friend, whether you like it or not.  You can look in the official C standard rationale if you want to seek a reason.  However, the C standard committee took existing (as in 'historical') practice very seriously and did not break what was already de facto standardized because existing C code was valuable.

Comment: @Igor Liferenko: C89/90 originally did not have wide character types. `char` was too narrow to afford a "reserved" value. For which reason the corresponding I/O library functions returned a wider type - `int` (`signed int`). And a negative `int` value was a natural choice for a "reserved" return value. Later, in C95 wide characters were added to the language. They did not need a wider integer type to represent a reserved value (`wchar_t` was considered wide enough for everything, including reserved values). Since `wchar_t` does not have to be signed, `WEOF` does not have to be signed either.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko For example standard i/0 functions that read characters return them in an object of type int as unsigned characters. To distinguish this return value that corresponds to eof from other unsigned characters it was decided to make EOF as signed int. In this case all high bits of the return value are set.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Because it used to be negative on most compilers and the standard copied from those compilers, then?

Comment: @immibis You are taking not about the cause - this is the consequence. OK, I will make my question more precise based on your comment: do you know the reason why "it used to be negative on most compilers"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "History is actually the main reason" - no, this is consequence. The reason is what made this "history".

Comment: OK; then the reasons are lost in the undocumented portions of pre-history.  I looked in the Unix Version 7 manuals (circa 1979).  Version 6 didn't have the standard I/O library; version 7 did.  The manuals simply say that EOF is -1 but you shouldn't depend on it.  The Rationale for the C standard doesn't say why EOF is negative.  It does mention that switch statements must support at least 257 cases to allow for 256 characters plus EOF; it also mentions that the macros in `<ctype.h>` must accept EOF and never return true for EOF.  It doesn't have any other mention of why EOF must be negative.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You asked why the standard requires EOF to be negative. The reason the standard requires EOF to be negative is (presumably) because most compilers made EOF negative and some programs checked for `<0` instead of `==EOF`.

Comment: @immibis why "most" compilers made EOF negative? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: The initial implementation of the Standard I/O library had EOF set to -1; almost all the compatible implementations therefore also made it -1.  For some reason, the standard only required it to be negative, not necessarily -1.  However, making it -1 simplifies things like the macros in `<ctype.h>` as it is contiguous with the (unsigned) character codes 0..255 which are typically used for characters in the basic character set.  So, the standard is more flexible than reality really needs; I've never heard of an implementation where EOF is not -1, though that doesn't prove that there isn't one.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Probably because some guy was like "Hey, what should this function return if the input is invalid? I know, maybe -1." If *you* were designing getchar what value would you have made it return on EOF?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the usual search on the internet is the case of the mercy. The history is scattered all over the world. But how to gather it in a single place? Was this already done by anybody? This means that the history of computing was not written... But the veterans are dying... This means that the living testimonies of its direct participants may be irrevocably lost for future generations... SOMETHING SHOULD BE DONE ABOUT THIS

Comment: You can find the [Unix Version 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix) manuals on the internet (though the top Google link seems to be dead); I know I've pointed to them in SO questions in times past.  There's [Lion's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions'_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code) book for Version 6 Unix source code.  And you can probably find [primeval C](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/primevalC.html) via a Google search, for instance.  The problem is knowing what to look for, of course.

Comment: @immibis I would have made it return `INT_MAX`